# Triangle with text involving white spaces

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw, white-space

I am drawing to draw a diagram in Latex exactly equivalent to this image:

[image]

I am having problems with the white spaces.  For instance, between "practice" and "management".

How would you code this in LaTeX?

Comment: Which problems do you have, excatly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `tikz`-package to achieve the desired result.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (b) at (4,0);
   \coordinate (c) at (2,2);
   \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a); % Triangle.
   \draw (2,1) node[anchor=north]{Platform};
   \draw (a) node[anchor=east,align=center] {Case\\ Management};
   \draw (b) node[anchor=west,align=center] {Practice\\ Management};
   \draw (c) node[anchor=south]{Billing};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With use labels for text at coordinates and barycentric coordinates for text inside triangle:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style = {align=center}
                        ]
\coordinate[label=left :Case\\ Management] (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:Practice\\ Management] (b) at (4,0);
\coordinate[label=above:Billing] (c) at (2,2);
%
\node at (barycentric cs:a=1 ,b=1 ,c=1) {Platform};
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]